# Rendering Graphics Somehow Producing NullPointerException

Tags: java, graphics, nullpointerexception, rendering, 2d-games

So I'm working on a sidescroller game in Java, and I just started working on the animations for the player. Everything was working okay up until this point. Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.blp.frisky.entity.Player.render(Player.java:58)
at com.blp.frisky.Controller.render(Controller.java:23)
at com.blp.frisky.gfx.Renderer.renderForeground(Renderer.java:41)
at com.blp.frisky.Game.render(Game.java:123)
at com.blp.frisky.Game.run(Game.java:154)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I noticed that the one thing all of the error locations have in common is rendering Graphics. Here's the first location that the error message is pointing to:

```
@Override
public void render(Graphics g) { //make player exist

    if(!moving){
        if(direction == Direction.RIGHT){ //facing right
            **g.drawImage(tex.playerStandingRight, (int) x, (int) y, null);** //draw still player if not moving while facing right
        }else if(direction == Direction.LEFT){ //facing left
            g.drawImage(tex.playerStandingLeft, (int) x, (int) y, null); ////draw still player if not moving while facing left
        }
    }else{
        if(direction == Direction.RIGHT){ //facing right
            animeRight.drawAnimation(g, x, y); //draw the animation right if moving
        }else if(direction == Direction.LEFT){ //facing right
            animeLeft.drawAnimation(g, x, y); //draw animation left if moving
        }
    }
}
```

What's interesting about this is that if I comment out the portion marked by asterisks above, my the game will run. Only, naturally, it won't show the texture with the player just standing and facing right. If I move though, the animations seem work fine. This leads me to believe that the problem stems from this method. I'd be happy to show more code if necessary. I've been stumped for a day or two now, and help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: The only possibility here, considering that drawImage accepts null as it's first parameter without failing fast (and isn't in your stacktrace), is that tex or g is null, you'll have to debug to find out yourself.

Comment: @NESPowerGlove That's right - except for the "classic": @asker: Do you call `getGraphics` on a component? (Most likely, because there appears no `paint...` call in the stack trace...)

Comment: NESPowerGlove Thanks a lot for that. I'll try and find it. @Marco13 Yeah I did call getGraphics on my BufferStrategy in my render method in the game class. I basically initializes a BufferStrategy, said if it's null to create the best one available, and then said:         Graphics g =  bs.getDrawGraphics Does that sound right or?

Comment: `getDrawGraphics` on a `BufferStrategy` is fine. **IF** you had done something like `game.render(someComponent.getGraphics());`, this **would** have explained the error, so this was my first guess (This first guess is the right one remarkably often, although not in this case)

Comment: @Marco13 So just an update. It turns out the null object was the bufferedimage in the texture class. I sort of fixed it by making the two standing idle images static and doing Texture. instead of tex. above. It'll have to do until I come across another solution but at least it runs. Thanks for helping out guys!